# Is there anyway to use the NDepend API to get a list of assemblies and their associated projects?

Tags: c#, api, static-analysis, ndepend

I am currently trying to get a list of 3rdParties shipped with each product and have come across the NDepend API. Based on the research I have done, it seems like you feed in a solution file and out comes a list of DLLs and EXE's associated with that solution. So far I have tried:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ndependServicesProvider = new NDependServicesProvider();
    var projectManager = ndependServicesProvider.ProjectManager;
    var visualStudioManager = ndependServicesProvider.VisualStudioManager;
    var projPath = "C:\\code\\depot\\Captiva\\IA\\EIM\\_Trunk\\Src\\BuildInputAccel.Installers.sln";
    var sln = projPath.ToAbsoluteFilePath();
    var vsSlnOrProjFilePaths = new List<IAbsoluteFilePath> { sln };
    var assembliesFilePath = (from vsSlnOrProjFilePath in vsSlnOrProjFilePaths

                              from assembliesFilePathTmp in visualStudioManager.GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject(vsSlnOrProjFilePath)

                              select assembliesFilePathTmp).Distinct().ToArray();
    IProject project = projectManager.CreateTemporaryProject(assembliesFilePath, TemporaryProjectMode.Temporary);
    project.CodeToAnalyze.SetApplicationAssemblies(assembliesFilePath);
    projectManager.SaveProject(project);
    IAnalysisResult analysisResult = project.RunAnalysis();
    Console.Write(analysisResult.CodeBase);



}
```

And have gotten a An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here. I simply want to output a list of dll's and exes associated with each project within a solution. PS: I am very new to C# so sorry if this seems trivial!

Answer (score 1):

At the [end of the NDepend API getting started](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html) page you'll find instruction about what to do.

Actually can use the integrated [Code Querying LINQ (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL) facility to query live 3rd party assemblies referenced and their usage.

1) from the NDepend start page > Analyze VS solution

2) choose your solution

3) run analysis

Then you can just edit this code query:

```
from a in ThirdParty.Assemblies
select new { a, a.AssembliesUsingMe }
```

et voilà

[image: NDepend querying for third-parties assemblies usage]

If some third-party assemblies are missing it is because they haven't been resolved at analysis time. Look at analysis error list and update the list of folder where NDepend will look for assemblies in NDepend Project Properties > Code to Analyze > Directories

[image: NDepend project properties folders that contain assemblies]

Comment: this is great thanks! I am still having trouble with the 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll error when trying to create a Ndepend project programmatically. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: I have followed all of the steps from the getting started section from the NDepend API

Comment: could you please double check this step  "all NDepend assemblies must be present in $NDependInstallPath$\ and $NDependInstallPath$\Lib."   NDepend.API.dll is actually relying on all other NDepend assemblies so they must be deployed with it

Comment: I have been given an NDependDeveloperProLicense.xml after upgrading. Where do I place this file so I can run an Analysis programatically. I keep getting this recurring error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in NDepend.Analysis.dll

Additional information: Cannot run analysis without a Build Machine license.

Comment: isn't "Cannot run analysis without a Build Machine license" self explaining? you need to Build Machine license to run analysis with NDepend.API http://www.ndepend.com/editions

Comment: it is very explaining. Stupid question with easy fix. Thanks for the help!